# How can I tune rigidity, stiffness or turnrate for an edge in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm attempting to draw some CFGs showing the internal node structure as well as the control edges between subgraphs.

In the image you can see how the thick back-edge that goes from `JUMP` to `ENTRY` takes a very sharp turn and goes through the subgraph itself. Likewise you can see back-edges from t19 snake itself through the basic block (subgraph) itself, rather than going on the outside.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to make the back-edges go on the outside of the subgraphs, but my immediate concern is finding a way to enforce a lower turn-rate which allows me to make edges that can't "turn on a dime".

The code generating the edges:

```
g0op14->g1op0[color=black, weight = 5, penwidth=5, tailport=s, headport=n];
g0op14->g2op0[color=black, weight = 5, penwidth=5, tailport=s, headport=n];
g1op8->g3op0[color=black, weight = 5, penwidth=5, tailport=s, headport=n];
g3op15->g2op0[color=black, weight = 5, penwidth=5, tailport=s, headport=n];

// Misbehaving edge below.
g3op15->g3op0[color=black, weight = 5, penwidth=5, tailport=s, headport=n, constraint = false];
g0op8->g1op1[color=black, tailport=s, headport=n];
```

On a meta-level, I'm not sure how to input images in my question. The way they're laid out now make them take up way too much space, I'd like to display them as clickable thumbnails instead of as enormous images inline.
This is my first real question, so feedback on how to make it more useful is appreciated.

[image: Basic Block 3]

The full CFG:

[image: Full CFG]

Comment: Please include the source.  I think the answer to your question is that there is no direct way to tune turnrate, rigidity & stiffness.  Turnrate seems to be radius of the curve.  Could you define rigidity & stiffness in this case?   I don't mind the image size, but you could remove "excess" from the source.   p.s. out of curiosity, what is a CFG?

Comment: I ended up using multiple words because they were the search terms I ended up using when trying to find out how to do this, so I figured at least others could benefit. Upon reflection I realize that the example is far too large to be meaningful, thus I'll first have to create reproduction without all the superfluous details. Maybe I can close the question temporarily until I have this ready.

CFG stands for Control Flow Graph, it's a way to represent instructions on a compiler. Each subgraph is a basic block, the "atom" (from a control flow perspective) of code.

Comment: Have you considered moving  "Entry" to a different rank (right above "Jump")